Removing whitespace between wrapped lines of highlights
I'm using soul to highlight some text. Here's how it looks now:

You'll notice there's a ton of white space between successive lines of highlighting. I'd like highlighting between successive lines (within a call to the highlight command) to be merged, like this:

I don't think there's any readymade library option to do this. Any ideas how I could pull it off? Thanks!
